# Angular2 : Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

I'm new in angular 2 and i try to make a reactive form but i have some trouble. After many search in stack i found no solutions.

Here you can see my error

[image]

The code :

View :

```html
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>User data</h2>
            <form [formGroup]="userForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
                </div>
                <div class="" formGroupName="adresse">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Rue</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="rue">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ville</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="ville">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cp</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="cp">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
```

My module.ts

```js
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ContactComponent } from './contact.component';
    import { FormGroup , FormControl , ReactiveFormsModule , FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        NgModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormGroup,
        FormControl
      ],
      declarations: [
        ContactComponent
      ]
    })
    export class ContactModule {}



And my component.ts

    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup , FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'contact',
      templateUrl: './contact.component.html'
      // styleUrls: ['../../app.component.css']
    })
    export class ContactComponent {
    
        userForm = new FormGroup({
            name: new FormControl(),
            email: new FormControl(),
            adresse: new FormGroup({
                rue: new FormControl(),
                ville: new FormControl(),
                cp: new FormControl(),
            })
        });
    }
```

I don't understand my error because import of ReactiveForm is here. So ... i need your help :) Thanks

After I read your answer and refactoring my code, it's ok, that works! The problem was i import reactive module in the module of my page contact and i need import this in module of my app. So thanks a lot for your interest :)

Hope this answer help another people guys.

Comment: Remove `FormGroup` and `FormControl` fom your imports in your ngModule...

Comment: You have a lot of other errors that you have to remove too.

Comment: Why are `NgModule`,`FormGroup` and `FormControl` in `imports` array of your module ?

Comment: your code seems work well, see is there any differences from this plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/mSLpeHxUzjT6bxcEO3zi?p=preview

Comment: @Pengyy I think he is totally ignoring the fact his code does not compile, so the browser reloads anyway, but it's still the error he tried to fix with these strange imports.

Comment: @Cyril, please check compile-time errors and post them.

Comment: No more comment... He's probably dead....

Comment: Sorry i was away trying by myself. It's ok it' work. After reading your answer. I import reactiveform in the module of my page and not in the app.module. I'm new with code and angular and it's not really easy to understand how is work. Thanks a lot  for your time

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think that this is an old error that you tried to fix by importing random things in your module and now the code does not compile anymore. while you don't pay attention to the shell output, the browser reload, and you still get the same error.

Your module should be :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ContactComponent
  ]
})
export class ContactModule {}
```

Comment: any output (in the shell, not the browser console) ?

Comment: I would also import CommonModule instead of BrowserModule because ContactModule doesn't look like root module

Comment: @yurzui nevermind if it's not lazy-loaded, but who knows ? I edited.

Comment: There must be one, it's the only explaination. Please, run again the command you use to start the compilation and post the whole output in your question.

Comment: It's ok, it's work. It's just a mess in my code with my different page. after read your answer and adapt my code it's ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: Forgot the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the `imports`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks , and these imports must exist in any module at the project

Comment: After hours of googling, this is the answer that fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

try with

`<form formGroup="userForm">`

instead of

`<form [formGroup]="userForm">`

Comment: What will it give?

Answer (score 7):

Try to add ReactiveFormsModule in your component as well.

```
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder,
          Validators,ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';
```

Answer (score 2):

For those still struggling with the error, make sure that you also import ReactiveFormsModule in your component 's module.ts file

meaning that you will import your ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module.ts and also in your *mycomponent.module.ts* file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved the problem in another way, without import ReactiveFormsModule.
You may be but this block in

```
ngOnInt(){

    userForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(),
        email: new FormControl(),
        adresse: new FormGroup({
            rue: new FormControl(),
            ville: new FormControl(),
            cp: new FormControl(),
        })
     });
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by importing FormModule in a shared.module and importing the shared.module in all other modules. My case is the FormModule is used in multiple modules.

Answer (score 0):

import the ReactiveForms Module to your components module

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the https://stackoverflow.com/tour, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer