# Angular 6: Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular4-forms

I am new to Angular 6 and working on ReactiveForms. Getting this error and unable to compile. I have seen the different solutions and Added the ReactiveFormsModule directive in Imports as suggested in solutions still it is showing the same error. Please Help.

Sharing you the desired code and screenshot of the error.
**app.module.ts**

```ts
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SignupFormComponent } from './signup-form/signup-form.component';
import { AuthorsService } from './authors.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignupFormComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    AuthorsComponent,
    FavoriteComponent,
    TitleCasePipe,
    PanelComponent,
    LikeComponent,
    ZippyComponent,
    ContactFormComponent,
    NewCourseFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

**Signup-form.ts**

```ts
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'signup-form',
  templateUrl: './signup-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup-form.component.css']
})
export class SignupFormComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(),
    password: new FormControl()
  });

}
```

**signup-form.html**

```html
<form [FormGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input 
            formControlName="username"
            id="username" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input 
            formControlName="password"
            id="password" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjiV7.png)

Comment: Try without the brackets

Comment: Did you try using the form builder to create your form group ?

Comment: @EduardoVargas without brackets? sorry i didnt get you.

Comment: @trichetriche yes

Comment: <form formGroup="form">

Comment: @EduardoVargas `<form [formGroup]="form">`

Comment: @EduardoVargas shows this
 ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

      Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

Comment: Sorry try <form formGroupName="form">

Comment: Here is the link to the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248849/angular2-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Comment: Here is the solution: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248849/angular2-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form)

Answer (score 3):

Please use below HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
...
</form>
```

The error is there since you are using capital F in [formGroup].

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @srashtisj and @suresh-kumar-ariya, you have to update the convention from `FormGroup` to `formGroup` in your HTML form, and everything should be working fine.

> [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) tracks the same values and status for a collection of form controls.

Learn more about to create form instance at [Angular's official Form guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance).

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to [FormGroup], use [formGroup]. Created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbp9fc

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormBuilder as this

```
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl , ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
constructor(private builder: FormBuilder){}

 public complexForm: FormGroup = this.builder.group({
  'firstname' : '',
  'lastname': '',
});
```

In Html

```
<form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(complexForm.value)">

 <div class="form-group" >
       <label>First Name:</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="John" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['firstName']">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

include `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `app.module.ts` all directives, which are using like `formGroup` etc.

They are defined in this module.