# Angular unit test error - Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am getting "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'" error (it('should create', () => {} ) test for every component using formGroup in my app. The app is working fine.

I have imported FormsModule & ReactiveFormsModule in every module.

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadDocumentFormGroup">

export class UploadFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public uploadDocumentFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private modalMessageService: ModalMessageService,
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm(): void {
     this.uploadDocumentFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        uploadDescription: FormFields.default()
      });
  }
```

upload-form.component.spec.ts

```
describe('UploadFormComponent', () => {
  let component: UploadFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UploadFormComponent>;
  // let formBuilder: FormBuilder
  // let modalMessageService: ModalMessageService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UploadFormComponent ],
      providers: [ ModalMessageService, FormBuilder ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UploadFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Please, help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 7 testing: "Can't bind to formGroup since it isn't a known property of form"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713782/angular-7-testing-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're using `ReactiveForms` so you have to add this module to your imports.

```
  import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  ...
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ UploadFormComponent ],
      providers: [ ModalMessageService, FormBuilder ],
      // add this line
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```