# Error - Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to make a form on an ionic page, but I've that error.
[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eKxt.png)

[image]

I've been searching the problem, and the more popular solution is import ReactiveFormsModule, but as you can see, It's correctly imported. How can the problem be?

The form is located in a page (editpage) that is launched from tab2 page as a modal.

The controller (editpage.page.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editpage',
  templateUrl: './editpage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editpage.page.scss'],
})
export class EditpagePage implements OnInit {
  public todoForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    navParams: NavParams,
    public modalController: ModalController) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.todoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['']
    });
  }

public addNote(){

  }
}
```

The html form:

```
<form [formGroup]="todoForm" (ngSubmit)="addNote()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>TODO</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>DESCRIPCION</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button shape="round" color="primary" fill="solid" type="submit" >Agregar
    </ion-button>
  </form>
```

Editpage.module.ts

```
import { Component, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EditpagePage } from './editpage.page';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [EditpagePage]
})
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-page',
})

export class EditpagePageModule {
  constructor(){}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    Flashlight,
    Geolocation
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: why is there a component decorator underneath your module declaration? seems problematic to me. and where is your edit page module imported into the main app? is it lazy loaded?

Comment: I have tried the 2 things you say and I continue with the problem.

Comment: Here is the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248849/angular2-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the imports from your component:

```
// REMOVE THIS:
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editpage',
  templateUrl: './editpage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editpage.page.scss'],
})
export class EditpagePage implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

2. From the `Editpage.module.ts` remove the @Component decorator

```
@NgModule({
  ...
})

// REMOVE THIS:
@Component({
  selector: 'modal-page',
})

export class EditpagePageModule {
  constructor(){}
```

3. From `app.module.ts` remove `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` from the imports
4. In `app.module.ts` import `EditpagePageModule`

Here is a minimal stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2g3wn

There's a lot going on in your samples, once you do these, and if it still doesn't work, I suggest you post a stackblitz example.